# Keeping existing google api client on configuration change

Tags: android

I am working on an app that has a google API client object. The object is in a fragment and is setup for auto manage. My problem is that after a configuration changes my object is null and when I try to re setup the client I get an error that a client is already being managed. What is the correct way to make the client persist when configuration changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your Api Client object as bundle in method `onSaveInstanceState()` and assign it back using `onRestoreInstanceState()`

(or)

Maintain a Singleton Client in Application class which will created only once and use any times throughout the Application Life Cycle

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will try this out.